# How to make PROVIDED to POM type dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

I am using the below dependency in my pom file for resolving compilation error. I have make its scope to provided but still the the related dependency jars are added while building the WAR file. Kindly do help me about how to proceed on this.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
        <type>pom</type>            
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is that dependency really of type `pom`, not `jar`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. it is pom .. Jorn.

Comment: Just to add more info .. The above dependency is a separate artifact of packaging type POM and if that dependency is added, then the dependencies defined there will be included in the individual artifact where the dependency of type POM is added.

Comment: I think the only time where dependecy type pom is used would be with scope `import` in a `dependencyManagement` section (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)

Comment: Oh ok, I forgot about that usecase. I just tried it on a project and here it is working as expected, when scope is set to `provided` the dependencies are not packaged.

Comment: Really !! ?? The dependency jars get packed for me. I dont know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you sure that the dependency with scope provided is not getting included as part of some other dependency ? have you checked the dependency graph  of your pom ?